# It is possible to UPDATE and SELECT in single statement using OUTPUT clause with CTE containing JOIN?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

We have a number of stored procedures that are used by BizTalk to fetch *n* rows from a queue (and a joined table) and update the status of those items at the same time.

I am trying to modify these queries to remove the use of table variables and instead do the work in a single statement.  I have succeeded with some, but this particular example is tricky because there is a `join` in the CTE, and I want to return some of the joined columns even though they weren't part of the `update`.

This is what I have come up with:

```
;with q as
(
    select top (@FetchCount) 
        iq.InQueueId,
        itk.[Message],
        iq.PatNo,
        iq.DistrictNo,
        itk.Interaction,
        iq.[Status]
    from
        InQueue iq
        join Itk on iq.InQueueId = itk.InQueueId
        join [Endpoint] e on iq.[Endpoint] = e.EndpointId
        join EndpointName en on en.EndpointNameId = e.Name
    where
        en.Name = 'XYZ'
        and iq.[Status] = @StatusNew
    order by
        iq.InQueueId
)
update
    q
set
    [Status] = @StatusSelected
output
    inserted.InQueueId as [Id],
    inserted.[Message] as [Msg],
    inserted.DistrictNo,
    inserted.Interaction
```

This immediately fails with the following error:

> The column reference "inserted.Message" is not allowed because it
>   refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.

Clearly this is because the columns **Message** and **Interaction** cannot be returned as part of the `inserted` set, because they are in a different table and therefore weren't updated.

So I attempted to change the `output` clause to:

```
output
    inserted.InQueueId as [Id],
    q.[Message] as [Msg],
    inserted.DistrictNo,
    q.Interaction
```

This fails with the error:

> The multi-part identifier "q.Message" could not be bound.

Is it possible to achieve this without rewriting the query to use either temporary tables or table variables?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `deleted` set in the output clause to reference columns in your CTE in tables that are not updated

e.g.

```
output
    inserted.InQueueId as [Id],
    deleted.[Message] as [Msg],
    inserted.DistrictNo,
    deleted.Interaction
```

The `deleted` and `inserted` sets in an `update` could also be thought of as before and after, although the terminology here matches `delete...output` and `insert...output`

Comment: Thanks, that was the one thing I didn't try!  I think they really could have improved the keyword choice here; it doesn't seem logical to look in the `deleted` set for values that have not changed.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to solve a problem I encountered.  I wish I could +10 this answer.